# How do I stop siblings from moving when transforming div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a Javascript which scales a div, amongst other things, when hovered on. The problem is that the siblings to that div move when it resizes. I understand why this happens, but I don't know how to stop it. I've tried to change the z-index but it doesn't stop the others from moving.

```
$(".medarbetareObjekt").mouseenter(function () {
$(this.getElementsByTagName("address")[0]).css("display", "inline");
$(this).css("background-color", "#f2f2f2");
$(this).css("font-weight", "100");
$(this).css("z-index", "1000");
$(this).css("width", "40%");
$(this).css("border-radius", "10px");
$(this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]).css("width", "80%");
$(this.getElementsByClassName("img-circle")[0]).css("margin-top", "5px");
}).mouseleave(function () {
$("address").css("display", "none");
$(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
$(this.getElementsByClassName("img-circle")[0]).css("margin-top", "0px");
$(".medarbetareObjekt").css("font-weight", "300");
$(this).css("z-index", "10");
$(this).css("width", "20%");
$(this).css("border", "none");
$(this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]).css("width", "100%");
});
```

So to sum it all up, how do I resize a div without affecting other divs?

https://jsfiddle.net/mellquist/58jmo1au/31/

Comment: Woah... you should cache `$(this)` by assigning to a variable and also you should use css object to declare multiple properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this css..

```
.zoom {
  -webkit-transform:scale(2);
  -moz-transform:scale(2);
  transform:scale(2);
}
```

And modified your script to add with these lines ..

`$(this).addClass("zoom")` and `$(this).removeClass("zoom")`

**Plus I removed a lot of the transforms and such from both your script and css.** In doing so I somehow remove the centering of your text below the images. I will leave that to you to trouble shoot

here is an updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pokd8jv9/2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't do what I was looking for. I tried it before I posted here and got the same result...

Comment: I added a " after absolute in your code:

$(this).css("position", "absolute"); 

Thats where the problem is... :(

Comment: Sorry you were right. It was only sort of working before. :(  I have updated my answer with a much better solution.